# issue creating an user with calculated field fastAPI

Tags: python, python-3.x, api, fastapi

I have a simple API to insert data inside an object type dictionary, my issue is when I try to save a calculated field. Example code:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()

users = {}
class User(BaseModel):
    name: str
    email: str
    calculated: float

@app.post('/user-create/{id_user}')
def creating_an_user(id_user:int,user:User):

    calculated = 1+2+3*2

    if id_user in users:
        return {"Error":"User ID already exists."}

    users[id_user] = {
        "name":user.name,
        "email":user.email,
        "calculated":user.calculated #should I need to put just like that ?
    }

    return users[id_user]
```

Obviously I receive an error, I think because my method is waiting a manually insert "calculated" field but is not:
`TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': Request with GET/HEAD method cannot have body.`

I am lost in this concern, can anybody help me on this?

Comment: Your `fetch` error is also unrelated to the Python question; you're trying to make a fetch request with a body - did you mean to make a POST request?

Comment: Have you tested this code using swagger on {url}/docs ? Code seems to be working, so most likely @MatsLindh comment should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks both @MatsLindh and @Chris, looks like `"calculated": calculated` this works